# How can I escape curly braces at the end of a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, posix-ere

I have the following bash script to replace parenthesis for curly braces.

```
VARS=${VARS//(/{}
VARS=${VARS//)/}}
```

The first line works OK, but the second one will only add a curly brace at the end.

If I try to escape the curly brace with a backslash, the backslash itself gets stored in the variable.

Is there a different way to escape these curly braces from the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative method:

```
VARS=`echo ${VARS} | tr '()' '{}'`
```

Although it seems like escaping the curly brace with a backslash is working, here is what I was using:

```
VARS=${VARS//(/{}
VARS=${VARS//)/\}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the first `}` so that bash does not think this is the end of the expression:

```
VARS=${VARS//)/\}}
```